# Set containing $\tilde{C}^c$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be the complement of a cantor like set $\tilde{C}$ in $[0,1]$ with $$\mu(\tilde{C}) = 1- \sum_ {n \geq 1} 2^{n - 1} I_n$$ where $I_n$ is the length of the middle interval removed at each step $n$

We are told that there exists an $\epsilon >0 $ such that for **any** closed set for any closed set $B$ containing the complement $A = [0,1] \setminus \tilde{C}$, we have: $$\mu(B-A)> \epsilon$$

First does this mean that $B$ is non-measurable? Because the measurability of a set is defined in terms of open sets and closed sets in a way that, $E$ is measurable if there exists a closed set $F \subset E$, such that $\mu(E-F) < \epsilon$

Comment: The statement (you are supposed to have been 'told') makes no sense at all.

Comment: Also note that $B \setminus A \subset C$ so $\mu (B \setminus A)=0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm would the statement be true for a cantor like set with measure $> 0$

Comment: Do you mean 'for **any** closed set $B$ we have $A \subset B$ and...' or 'for **any** closed set $B$ **such that**  $A \subset B$ we have....'$?

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is a closed set in $[0,1]$ containing the complement of $\tilde{C}$ then $U=[0,1]\setminus B$ is an open set contained in $\tilde{C}$. But $\tilde{C}$ has no interior, so $U$ must be empty. Thus $\mu (B\setminus A)=\mu (\tilde C)$. Take $\epsilon =\frac 1  2\mu (C)$.

Comment: Got it now. I thought the question was about some special set that is related to the cantor set, similar to the Smith–Volterra–Cantor set.